# Encoding issue posting complex model using $.get and @(Html.Raw(Json.Encode(model)))

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have an application that makes use of $.get to switch sections of the page between edit and view pages.

(in this example I am passing the whole model cause it makes the code easier to read)

```
$.get(@(Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Url.Action("_Table")))),
        @(Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))),
        function (data) { $('#@(Model.Guid)').empty().append(data)}
    );
```

The issue is that while simple attributes (int, string etc) are passed back to the action fine any complex object is not passed back correctly.

I used Request.QueryString.ToString() to see what is being passed to the action and this is recieved.

```
{Guid=e1207e1c-78b6-4592-ab49-3ab9fa43a0e3&ExecuteSearch=True&ShowSearch=True&AllowExport=True&SearchData%5bId%5d=0&SearchData%5bName%5d=tes&SearchData%5bHostname%5d=null&SearchData%5bDescription%5d=null&SearchData%5bisActive%5d=false}
```

I was expecting

```
{Guid=0d7cfe4d-c75f-40fb-ba9a-faee58abfeaa&ExecuteSearch=True&ShowSearch=True&AllowExport=True&SearchData.Id=&SearchData.Name=tes&SearchData.Hostname=&SearchData.Description=}
```

Note "SearchData.Id" instead of "SearchData%5bId%5d="

Here is the Model.

```
public class VM_List
{
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
    public Boolean ExecuteSearch { get; set; }
    public Boolean ShowSearch { get; set; }
    public Boolean AllowExport { get; set; }
    public Boolean MultiEdit { get; set; }
    public String Title { get; set; }
    public String NewText { get; set; } //If null then link is not shown
    public dynamic SearchData { get; set; }
    public dynamic Data { get; set; }

    public VM_List(Guid Guid, Boolean ExecuteSearch, Boolean ShowSearch, Boolean AllowExport, Boolean MultiEdit, String Title, String NewText, dynamic SearchData, dynamic Data)
    {
        this.Guid = Guid;
        this.ExecuteSearch = ExecuteSearch; 
        this.ShowSearch = ShowSearch;
        this.AllowExport = AllowExport;
        this.MultiEdit = MultiEdit;
        this.Title = Title;
        this.NewText = NewText;
        this.SearchData = SearchData;
        this.Data = Data;
    }
}
```

Anyone have any ideas on what is causing the encoding error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a JSON request if you want to send complex objects:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("_Table")';
var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(model),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function(result) {
        $('#' + model.Guid).empty().append(result);
    }
});
```

The `JSON.stringify` method serializes the `model` javascript model variable into a JSON string to be sent to the controller action. Thismethod is natively built into modern browsers but if you want to support legacy browsers you might need to include the [`json2.js`](http://www.json.org/js.html) script to your page.

Comment: Thank you for the replay but i have already tried Stringify. This code produces a URL like `http://localhost:50873/GMPServer/_Table?{%22Guid%22:%2238df40eb-b336-4062-846c-3dad2caf2a63%22,%22ExecuteSearch%22:true,%22ShowSearch%22:true,%22AllowExport%22:true,%22MultiEdit%22:false,%22Title%22:%22GMP%20Servers%22,%22NewText%22:%22New%20GMP%20Server%22,%22SearchData%22:{%22Id%22:0,%22Name%22:%22tes%22,%22Hostname%22:null,%22Description%22:null,%22isActive%22:false},%22Data%22:{%22Name%22:null,%22Hostname%22:null,%22Description%22:null,%22isActive%22:true}}` which the action does not understand.

Comment: This works. Thank you. I had been playing around with stringify and it never worked. Didn't realise that it only worked with a POST.